How to Retrieve Other Member's Profile details though LinkedIn API? We are getting error with the permissions while trying to access through postman
I have created an access token with the scopes openid, profile, email and member_social. And Im trying to get the linked in profile details with the API URL GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/(id:{person ID}). But im getting error message as "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET /people/(id:xxx)",
We tried to resolve the error by trying to add more scopes. But that doesn't work. Also we tried with this API as well GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/clientAwareMemberHandles?q=handleString&handleString={someone@email.com}. But we are getting the same error message as "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-handleString /clientAwareMemberHandles",

I have the same problem. Were you able to find a solution?
